# No puedo visualizar mis estadísticas de Notificaciones Push Firebase

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-messaging, android-notifications

no si a ustedes le sucederá, lo mismo, pero en mi consola me sale que el 0% a hecho click, lo que me hace pensar que a nadie le llega la notificación. He colocado la foto de la misma app del 2022 y 2024, y verán que en el 2022 si me marcaba y se sentía la gente que entraba. Solo quiero  saber si es un problema de la consola o mi app no estará mandado las notificaciones a nadie

PD: A mi teléfono si que llegan las notificaciones desde el firebase, pero no se porque allí dice 0%, igualmente no se siente que entre nadie al enviarlas.

[image: Foto 2022]

[image: Foto 2024]

Answer (score 0):

Es super importante que sepas que **desde Android 13 (nivel de API 33) y versiones posteriores admiten un permiso de tiempo de ejecución para enviar notificaciones el cual debe ser aceptado por el usuario**, si el usuario no acepta ahora este permiso no podrá recibir Push Notifications.

Ahora debes declarar el permiso [POST_NOTIFICATIONS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS) en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

y obviamente requerir el permiso manualmente:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);

    } 
    else {
      //* Permiso concedido por el usuario.
     }
    }
```

Revisa:

[**Permiso de tiempo de ejecución: notificaciones**](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission?hl=es-419)

Comment: Excelente, ya lo voy a implementar y verificar todo